# Empty element and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I try to parse site and i have problem. When i parse table with empty element

```
type = elements[i].getElementsByClassName("listing-item__type");
```

I have this

```
VM56462:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:7:25
```

How to fix it? Is it possible to check the element for empty?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Because `getElementsByClassName` return an array, you can not treat array as DOM element, you need get index and use

```
if (type[0] != undefined && type[0].innerText){
// add code here
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns HTMLCollection, not array.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your HTML structure, you can check the presence of an element through:

```
if (type) {
   // "type" is not undefined
}
```

Please note also that your "type" will return an array of elements (since you're using `getElementsByClassName`). Access the first one and check it is truthy before checking for the `.innerText`.